# Shiny - Updating UI after API call inside observeEvent

Tags: r, api, shiny

My UI has an activeButton and whenever the user presses it, the following observeEvent method calls an API and returns a numeric value.

```
observeEvent(input$submit, {

  url <- "http://my_ip/predict?"
  value <- paste0('value=', input$value)

  response <- POST(paste0(url,value))

  predicted <- as.numeric(content(response))
})
```

The problem is that I want to show the result ("predicted" variable) in a infoBox in the UI, but only when predicted has a value. Therefore, that infoBox has to be hidden until the user presses the button the first time.

What kind of output should I put in the UI?.
How could "predicted" behave like input$value?.

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT**

The solution was using the function `reactiveValues()` when calling the API:

```
reactiveValues <- reactiveValues()
reactiveValues$predicted <- as.numeric(content(response))
```

And then, using the function `renderInfoBox()` based on the previous value.

Comment: Have a look at [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) - to show & hide elements.

Comment: use `reactiveValues` to add the response to it. `reactiveValues$predicted <- as.numeric(content(response))` then bind it to the `infoBox`. http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/reactiveValues

Comment: It worked with @PorkChop solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: please dont confuse the readers and only accept relevant answers

Answer (score 1):

To update this from the comments above:

Use `reactiveValues` to add the response to it.

`reactiveValues$predicted <- as.numeric(content(response))`

then bind it to the `infoBox`